# Why is controlTextDidEndEditing being called when I send setEditable?

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield

```
//1:
-(void) TextFieldEdit:(CDTextField *)textField{
 [textField setEditable:YES];
}

//2:
 - (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
 NSTextField* textField = (NSTextField *)[aNotification object];
 [textField setEditable:NO];
}
```

I hope setEditable at time 1, and close it at time 2.

But I found when I sent setEditable Xcode immediately called the controlTextDidEndEditing:.

Why?

EDIT: The first method is invoked via the following sub-classed method:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
if ([event type]==1)
{
NSInteger key=[event modifierFlags];
if ( key & NSCommandKeyMask)
    {[self.delegate CDTextFieldEdit:self]; }
else
    if (event.clickCount >1)
    {[self.delegate CDTextFieldClicked:self]; return;}

 }
 [super mouseDown:event];
 }
```

Comment: *How* is the first method being called?

Comment: I subclassed it with CDTEXTField instead NSTEXTField. -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    //[super mouseDown:event];
   
    if ([event type]==1)//
  {
   
    NSInteger key=[event modifierFlags];
      //& ( key & NSAlternateKeyMask) & (key & NSControlKeyMask))

    if ( key & NSCommandKeyMask)
        {[self.delegate CDTextFieldEdit:self]; }
    else
        if (event.clickCount >1)
        {[self.delegate CDTextFieldClicked:self]; return;}
      
  }
    [super mouseDown:event];
}

Comment: Please edit your question appropriately.  I have a query about what looks like a spurious comment (`//`).